# FF+Firebug got an error "Regular Expression too complex", IE crashed and Chrome hung

Tags: javascript, regex

According to this http://www.utexas.edu/its/help/domain-name-hosting-and/847 then I made this regular expression:

`/^[a-z](\w+\.?\w*[a-z0-9]){5,17}@[a-z]((a-z0-9\-]{1,25}\.[a-z]{2,4})|([a-z0-9\-]{1,25}\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2,3}))$/;`

And throw this value:

**asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbn@yahoo.com**

Firefox + firebug says "Regular Expression too complex", IE Crashed and Chrome hung, is there something wrong with the regexp?

I use Javascript.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? What types of strings are you trying to match?

Comment: Guess you don't need to capture the grouped values, then using `(?:` instead of just `(` to start you groups will create non-capturing groups, what will cause the evaluation to be a bit faster and use less memory, maybe making it less complex to the engine.

Comment: but you are a Lieutenant! It should say "Ensign Dan" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Missing [

`/^[a-z](\w+\.?\w*[a-z0-9]){5,17}@[a-z]((`

here `[`

`a-z0-9\-]{1,25}\.[a-z]{2,4})|([a-z0-9\-]{1,25}\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2,3}))$/;`

Comment: doesn't solve the problem the regex is for, but definitely answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (your solution has misprint):

```
^[a-z](\w+\.?\w*[a-z0-9]){5,17}@[a-z](([a-z0-9\-]{1,25}\.[a-z]{2,4})|([a-z0-9\-]{1,25}\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2,3}))$
```

I think you forgot `[` in `(a-z0-9\-]{1,25}`

Answer (score 2):

The actual issue here (ignoring the missing `[`) is that you have a greedy qualifier (`/w+` and `/w*`) following by a range (`{5,17}`)

What this means is:

- find any number of `\w` characters
- filter down to 5-17

The engine only does the filter after it finds the "any number", and gets very confused here...

It's a weird expression anyway: `(\w+\.?\w*[a-z0-9]){5,17}` The `{5,17}` should almost certainly be on *part* of that, not the entire thing.

Comment: yeah I know I messed up.. anyway, what makes `/^(?:a)+(bcd)$/` be different from `/^(?:a+)(bcd)$/`?

Comment: Who said those were different?  The internal engine may do something slightly different with them, not sure, but they should function identically.  The issue is with multiple quantity qualifiers, things like `(a+)*`, `(a*){2,}`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

what if someone has email address like john.doe@media.company.info or jane.doe@company.office?

try this:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

http://regexpal.com/